# How to check in a working copy if the default workflow is plone_workflow or intranet_workflow?

Tags: plone

I ask myself how to check in a working copy if you use plone_workflow or intranet_workflow.

Setup: The default workflow is plone_workflow. In a folder is a page which is published. I am a user who can add, edit and review. But of course I am not an admin. Now I check out the page, edit and save it. Now, big surprise, I do not have the check-in link. I can only cancel the check-out.

But I can submit and publish the working copy. Then neither I can check in nor out. (No link there). Then I retract the working copy and try to retract the original. But this is not possible because there is a working copy. So: **It is impossible to check in the working copy.**

Btw. I have the permission to add and edit in the container.

In my opinion there should be the possibilty to check in the working copy independently from the workflow state. Am I right, or what do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was discussed 3 or 4 years ago in the Plone Issue Tracker. http://dev.plone.org/plone/ticket/7372

Recommendation: give the Owner and Editor roles "Modify portal content" in the published state .

Comment: Since you answered your own question, shouldn't you accept the answer.  :-)